# Compacting multiple similar if statements in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, if-statement

I would like to make some code for a game a little more compact. Here is the original.

```
if (killPosX != 0) // float x position you would like the object to be destroyed at
{
    killX = true;  // automatically makes the value of killX true
}

if (killPosY != 0) // float y position you would like the object to be destroyed at
{
    killY = true;  // automatically makes the value of killY true
}

if (killPosT != 0) // float position in time you would like the object to be destroyed at
{
    killT = true;  // automatically makes the value of killT true
}
```

And I want to turn it into something like this:

```
if ([killPosX, killPosY, killPosT] != 0)
{
    [killPosX, killPosY, killPosT] = true;
}
```

How would I do that?

Comment: In the second part, did you mean: killX, killY, killT vs killPosX...= true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (killPosX != 0)
{
    killX = true;
}
```

Could be translated as follow

```
killX = (killPosX != 0) ? true : killX;
```

Or more simply

```
killX |= killPosX != 0;
```

---

```
if (killPosX != 0)
{
    killX = true;
}
else
{
    killX = false;
}
```

Could be translated as follow

```
killX = (killPosX != 0) ? true : false;
```

Or more simply

```
killX = killPosX != 0;
```

---

But since comparing floats using `==` or `!=` is not advised, I would go for:

```
killX |= !Mathf.Approximately( killPosX, 0 );
killY |= !Mathf.Approximately( killPosY, 0 );
killT |= !Mathf.Approximately( killPosT, 0 );
```

---

**AFAIK**, there is no built-in syntax similar to what you wrote in order to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thank you, @Hellium, for such an extensive and thorough answer. Would you please be able to explain why "comparing floats using `==` or `!=` is not advised"?

Comment: You will find several resources on the "floating point imprecision" problem. I've arbitrarily [chosen one](https://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/). But even the author of this article would not advise my solution. I guess, in your case, it will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this applies to what you're working on (and there may be a better way in Unity), but it seems to me that one way to do it would be to make the `KillN` properties calculated on the value of their corresponding `KillPosN` property:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public float KillPosX { get; set; }
    public float KillPosY { get; set; }
    public float KillPosT { get; set; }

    // Values are based on the related property values and cannot be set directly
    public bool KillX => !IsRoughlyZero(KillPosX);
    public bool KillY => !IsRoughlyZero(KillPosY);
    public bool KillT => !IsRoughlyZero(KillPosT);

    private static bool IsRoughlyZero(float input)
    {
        // Use a tolerance for comparing floating point numbers to 0
        return Math.Abs(input) < .0000001;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way to do it as you suggest but it might be a little neater and more compact to use a variation of the approach hellium suggested:

```
public void fnc(ref bool t1, float t2) { t1 |= !Mathf.Approximately( t2, 0 ); }

fnc(ref KillX, KillPosX);
fnc(ref KillY, KillPosY);
fnc(ref KillT, KillPosT);
```

You could of course wrap it in a method which uses arrays as parameters but unless you need a generic way to do this for variable sized arrays, the setup cost is bulkier than just using discrete calls.